# Correlation Table with Color alignment issue

Tags: latex, tabular, tikz

I'm reproducing a previously asked question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174998/are-there-an-easy-way-to-coloring-tables-depending-on-the-value-in-each-cell

Here is my latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

 %The min, mid and max values
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{-1.0}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%

%Apply the gradient macro
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
        \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{blue!\PercentColor!white}{#1}
        \else
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{red!\PercentColor!white}{#1}
        \fi
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{RRRRRRRRRR}
 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.37 \\
              1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.95 & -0.90 & 0.82 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.01 \\
              1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.67 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.00 \\
              1.00 & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.78 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.00 \\
              0.99 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.98 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.67 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.95 & 0.78 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.90 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.82 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
              0.37 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The plot is as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdNZf.png)

The problem I have is that:
1. negative values have one more letter (negative sign), which causes the misalignment and the empty space between columns. 
2. At the extreme value, the color is too dark to see the number. I wish to color the cell white background when the value is 1.00

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!